# Apache canonical url 301 redirect and friendly url rewriting problem

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, apache2

I have the following issue:

I want to redirect a non-canonical url to the canonical one, but maintaning the friendly url rewriting.

In my .htaccess I have the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

#Protect some directories
RewriteRule ^(system|modules|application) - [F,L]

#Force Using Canonical Name
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com/$0 [R=301]

#Friendly url rewriting
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?route=$0 [QSA,L]
```

I have no problems with this address:

http://www.example.com/articles/10/this-is-a-sample-post.html

But when I try to access the same url without the "www." part,
it is redirected to:

http://www.example.com/index.php?route=articles/10/this-is-a-sample-post.html

In other words,

http://example.com/articles/10/this-is-a-sample-post.html

must be redirected to

http://www.example.com/articles/10/this-is-a-sample-post.html

Somebody knows where is the problem? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the fact that your external redirect needs to be performed first, but currently it actually takes places after your last rule block. Adding the [`L` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags) to force an immediate redirection will solve your problem:

```
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com/$0 [R=301,L]
```

Without the flag, the URL will be transformed again by the second rule block before the redirect happens, which is why you get the unexpected behaviour.